# Visualbrush binding in a style System.Windows.Data Error: 2

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, visualbrush

I just have a simple binding, it works well but there is an error popup.

The effects work but still an error.

And the error is 
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'VisualBrush' (HashCode=23487194); target property is 'Visual' (type 'Visual')

I have tried x: Reference but there would be another error.

Appreciated a lot if any can help.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border 
                           x:Name="RoundMask"
                           CornerRadius="10"
                           Background="white"/>

                            <!-- The main content -->
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.OpacityMask>
                                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=RoundMask}" />
                                </Grid.OpacityMask>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re templating a window like that is not really the way I'd go about this sort of thing.

I'd use something more like the approach in this sample:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ThWPFPolishing-Chrome-f41be7fe

Finished fancy window is
[image]

Window6, using WindowChrome styling which is in the resource dictionary Dictionary1.

Which has stuff lika a big round close button. But to give you the idea before downloading:

```
<Style x:Key="FinishedWindow" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DarkDark}"/>
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="0"
                          CornerRadius="20"
                          GlassFrameThickness="0"
                          NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                          ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                                    />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border   Background="{StaticResource BrightMid}"   BorderBrush="{StaticResource DarkLight}" BorderThickness="4,4,6,6" 
                         CornerRadius="12">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <BlurEffect  KernelType="Gaussian" Radius="12" RenderingBias="Quality" />
                        </Border.Effect>
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource DarkDark}" BorderThickness="2" 
                            CornerRadius="12" ClipToBounds="True">
                    </Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title}" 
                                          Foreground="{StaticResource DarkDark}"
                                          Grid.Row="0"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                          FontWeight="Bold"
                                          FontSize="16"
                                     />
                        <Button Name="CloseButton" 
                                Width="20" Height="20"   
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                Margin="0,12,12,0"
                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CloseCommand}"
                                Style="{StaticResource CloseButton}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Margin="12"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

I gave your style a go.

Just using it implicitly had no effect at all.

I put it in app.xaml and gave it a key

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" x:Key="roundedWindowStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border 
                       x:Name="RoundMask"
                       CornerRadius="10"
                       Background="white"/>

                        <!-- The main content -->
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=RoundMask}" />
                            </Grid.OpacityMask>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

And then I applied that to mainwindow

```
<Window
    ...
    Title="MainWindow" 

    Style="{StaticResource roundedWindowStyle}"
```

Hit f5... and it kind of works. Well.

If you ignore that window chrome means it cannot work as you seem to intend.

[image]

You probably ought to be looking at using window chrome instead.

With what you have there.

At the absolute minimum, you need a Contentpresenter inside that Grid.
Because a window is a content control but it won't show any content at all if you have no contentpresenter in the template.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply, but this actually isn't the issue that I am facing, I didn't include the content part and the chrome part, but the problem is caused by VisualBrush, as using visual brush binding in a style will cause an exception.

Comment: See the second picture? Using the visual brush binding in a style.  No exception.

Comment: Hi Andy thank you so much, I think I know why this happened. It's because I pack ed this style in a dll,. If I put it in the app.xaml it works well. But since it's a messagebox I still want to put it in a dll for referencing.

Comment: And when the window inside the dll reference this style it will cause this error, but the other normal window can use this freely.